# What exactly does the ability Demolition+ affect?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-online

Does it affect stun and sleep grenades? Grenade launchers? Sleep grenade launchers? Sleep mines? Anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of what all is affected: Based on a post [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/181901-metal-gear-solid-v-metal-gear-online/72634654), it looks like sleep grenades are affected. Stun grenades are not confirmed, but I think it is a safe assumption, since it *is* a grenade and it explodes and all.

> Sleep grenade confirmed, stun grenade presumed yes.

Based on the image I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/mgo/comments/3nz95x/mgo_unlocks_and_upgrades_table/), the first tier of Demolition+ appears to increase the damage done by all explosives, which would definitely include regular grenades (and launchers, by relation), as well as sleep grenades/mines and its launcher, as supported by the above post.

[image]

In addition, the second tier of Demolition+ adds the feature of tossing a live grenade upon death.

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no image for what the third tier of Demolition+ does, however, I found [this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/181901-metal-gear-solid-v-metal-gear-online/72623050) that has the description:

> Enforcer - Demolition 3 - grenades explode as soon as they land. - really useful, especially for entrenched enemies or if you are pinned down.